# assign values on the on the number of seconds into a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to generate a new column having the same values for range of time (5 seconds)

I have the time column but want to generate `X` column as shown below.

```
Time                  X
2017-10-31 11:11:20   1
2017-10-31 11:11:20   1
2017-10-31 11:11:22   2
2017-10-31 11:11:22   2
2017-10-31 11:11:22   2
2017-10-31 11:11:23   3
2017-10-31 11:11:23   3
2017-10-31 11:11:23   3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect your initial data frame looks like this:

```
>> print(df)
                  Time
0  2017-10-31 11:11:20
1  2017-10-31 11:11:20
2  2017-10-31 11:11:22
3  2017-10-31 11:11:22
4  2017-10-31 11:11:22
5  2017-10-31 11:11:23
6  2017-10-31 11:11:23
7  2017-10-31 11:11:23
```

If this assumption is true, you can make a new pandas series with encoding for `X` column and map this series on `Time` column after that, using `.map` method. The code is following.

```
>> time_ser = df.Time.value_counts().sort_index()
>> time_ser = pd.Series(list(range(1, len(time_ser) + 1)), index=time_ser.index)
>> df['X'] = df.Time.map(time_ser)
>> print(df)

                  Time  X
0  2017-10-31 11:11:20  1
1  2017-10-31 11:11:20  1
2  2017-10-31 11:11:22  2
3  2017-10-31 11:11:22  2
4  2017-10-31 11:11:22  2
5  2017-10-31 11:11:23  3
6  2017-10-31 11:11:23  3
7  2017-10-31 11:11:23  3
```